# need to convert a code to make it compatible with a Version 5 strategy

Tags: pine-script

I would like to go from version 1 to version 3 4 or 5.
Can you help me for this MACD study to achieve this conversion?

see below:

```
//@version=1

    "study(shorttitle = "MACD 4C", title = "4 colour MACD")
    fastMA = input(title="Fast moving average", type = integer, defval = 12, minval = 7)
    slowMA = input(title="Slow moving average", type = integer, defval = 26, minval = 7)
    lastColor = yellow
    [currMacd,_,_] = macd(close[0], fastMA, slowMA, 9)
    [prevMacd,_,_] = macd(close[1], fastMA, slowMA, 9)
    
    signalLength=input(9,minval=1)
    signal = sma(currMacd, signalLength)
    
    plotColor = currMacd > 0 
        ? currMacd > prevMacd ? lime : green 
        : currMacd < prevMacd ? maroon : red
    plot(currMacd, style = columns, transp=20, color = plotColor, linewidth = 3)
    plot(0, title = "Zero line", linewidth = 1, color = gray)
    plot(signal, color=white, transp=0, title="Signal")
    "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator(shorttitle = "MACD 4C", title = "4 colour MACD")
fastMA = input.int(title="Fast moving average", defval = 12, minval = 7)
slowMA = input.int(title="Slow moving average", defval = 26, minval = 7)
lastColor = color.yellow
[currMacd,_,_] = ta.macd(close[0], fastMA, slowMA, 9)
[prevMacd,_,_] = ta.macd(close[1], fastMA, slowMA, 9)

signalLength= input.int(9,minval=1)
signal = ta.sma(currMacd, signalLength)

plotColor = currMacd > 0 ? currMacd > prevMacd ? color.lime : color.green : currMacd < prevMacd ? color.maroon : color.red
plot(currMacd, style = plot.style_columns, color = color.new(plotColor,20), linewidth = 3)
plot(0, title = "Zero line", linewidth = 1, color = color.gray)
plot(signal, color=color.new(color.white,0), title="Signal")
```

Comment: That s great. Thanks a lot Marcus!